# What is the best way to deal with changing key names on a JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I was wondering if there is a way to transform this JSON in a way that instead of having **"2020-07-06"** as a key we would have a field **date: "2020-07-06"**. Its a large dataset so I can't manually change eveything.

```
{
  "2020-07-06": {
    "food": {
    },
  },
  "2020-07-07": {
    "food": {
      },
    },
  "2020-07-08": {
    "food": {
      },
    },
  }

Expected output:

{
  "date": "2020-07-06",
  "food": {
   },
  "date": "2020-07-07",
  "food": {
   },
  "date: "2020-07-08",
  "food": {
   },
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output for this input?

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. So if you *are* dealing with a string, the best thing is to parse it so it's not JSON anymore, then modify the resulting object. But I suspect you're not starting with a JSON string at all...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OP doesn't know how to handle dynamic keys without knowing them before hand. Looping through object, then can create in whatever format they want

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've reopened it. You can vote to close.

Comment: Thank you an sorry for the bad question, Im pretty new to this stuff

Comment: Please add your expected output.

Comment: Expected output added

Comment: Your expected output is invalid, you can't have multiple properties with the same name. Perhaps you want an array of objects.

Comment: I think you are right I want an array of objects, I guess I should delete the question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a look at this snippet. Guess this is a way to start with.

```js
const old = {
  "2020-07-06": {
      "food": {
    },
  },
  "2020-07-07": {
      "food": {
      },
    },
  "2020-07-08": {
      "food": {
      },
    },
}

const obj = Object.keys(old).map(e => {
   let res = old[e]
   res.date = e;
   return res;
});
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Alright. Note that this could have easily done with copy & paste. Feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: Actually I just realized that I need the date field on every date, I added my expected output

Comment: This is no valid JSON @stackoverlord. Note that every key can just be there a single time.

Comment: Ah you are right, i think TJ is right I want an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

The keys has to be unique, so the only clean way to solve this is using arrays. Here you have an example of solution:

```js
const input = {
  "2020-07-06": {
    "food": {
    },
  },
  "2020-07-07": {
    "food": {
      },
    },
  "2020-07-08": {
    "food": {
      },
    },
  }
  
  const res = Object.keys(input).map((key) => {
    return {
      food: input[key].food,
      date: key
     }
  });
  
  console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and then map over it to create an array

```js
const old = {
  "2020-07-06": {
      "food": {
    },
  },
  "2020-07-07": {
      "food": {
      },
    },
  "2020-07-08": {
      "food": {
      },
    },
    }

const newArray = Object.entries(old).map(([key, valueObject]) => {
  return { date: key, ...valueObject }
})

console.log(newArray)
```